# getting Blob:URL from $cordovaCamera, Not valid base64 string

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, cordova, ionic-framework

I am working on cordova mobile application, I need to upload an Image on server. I want to send base64 string to my webapi and there I can convert base64 to Image and save image on server. I am doing this $cordovaCamera in controller as

```
$scope.takePicture = function () {
        var options = {
            quality: 75,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
            allowEdit: true,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            targetWidth: 100,
            targetHeight: 100,
            popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
            correctOrientation: true
        };
        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
            console.clear();
            console.log(imageData);
            $scope.imgURI = imageData;
            $rootScope.ByteData = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        }, function (err) {
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Invalid Image',
                template: 'Please upload correct formated image!'
            });
        });
    }
```

But whenever I run this code I got **imageData** in form of specific URL like **"blob:http%3A//localhost%3A4400/f6c7fc38-a18f-484e-94d1-a52bb4e5fee2"**, How can I get base64 correct string in this scenario. In my view I am doing like

```
<ion-view view-title="{{application.CompanyName}}">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="primary">
        <button class="button" ng-click="saveApplication()">
            SAVE
        </button>
        <button class="button" ng-click="goBack()">
            BACK
        </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-content ng-controller="AppDetailCtrl">
        <img ng-show="imgURI !== undefined" width="343px" height="300px" ng-src="{{imgURI}}">
        <img ng-show="imgURI === undefined" width="343px" height="300px" ng-src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
        <button class="button" ng-click="takePicture()">Upload Picture</button>
    </ion-content>

</ion-view>
```

Comment: which version of camera plugin are you using? And which device are you tested on?

Comment: I am testing on visual studio, and cordova-plugin-camera with 2.2.0 version

Comment: I made a demo, but not reproducing the problem here, could you post a basic demo that can reproduce this problem? And which target device are you using?

Comment: ripple nexus (galaxy) chrome

Comment: @ElvisXia I just updated the question. I am doing this for android device.

Comment: Not regarding the question asked but you have written `ng-src="{{imgURI}}"`, you need to append  `data:image/jpeg;base64,` before it.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I want to convert that blob image url type to base64 string and I was missing bellow method of converting like

```
function convertImgToBase64(url, callback, outputFormat) {
                var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS'),
                    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
                    img = new Image;
                img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
                img.onload = function () {
                    var dataURL;
                    canvas.height = img.height;
                    canvas.width = img.width;
                    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                    dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
                    callback.call(this, dataURL);
                    canvas = null;
                };
                img.src = url;
            }
            convertImgToBase64(imageData, function (base64Img) {
                $rootScope.ByteData = base64Img;
            });
```